# How to pass multiple arguments in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a class in CSS here:

```
.border {
  border-color: var(--colorArg);
  border-style: var(--styleArg);
}
```

And I want to pass multiple arguments in the CSS class through HTML, like so:

```
<div class="border" style="--colorArg: blue --styleArg: outset;">
  <p>This is a website made as a practice website to learn HTML, CSS, and 
  JavaScript!</p>
</div>
```

Passing only `--styleArg: outset` works, it creates the border in the desired manner. But if I try to pass more than one, or just the color argument, there is no border created at all. Maybe because I need to make the argument the Hex code, or the RGB code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the style attribute. There needs to be a semi colon (;) between each property setting.

```css
.border {
  border-color: var(--colorArg);
  border-style: var(--styleArg);
}
```

```html
<div class="border" style="--colorArg: blue; --styleArg: outset;">
  <p>This is a website made as a practice website to learn HTML, CSS, and JavaScript!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Im new to CSS and HTML, so this is cool! :)

Comment: what about optional arguments? something like if the argument is not given, it will select a value automatically

Comment: If  a variable isn't defined it's well, undefined. If you don't want to set them all in JS you could put a value into the style sheet and then it can get overwritten at run time by the JS.